# Pointing to div of other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 html pages (say 1.html and 2.html) which I want to display in 2 different frames. 1.html contains a table with some rows. Each row contains some details which I have stored in 2.html using div for each row. Initially I want to hide these div's so nothing should be displayed in 2.html. Now when I select any row from 1.html, respective details (div) in 2.html should be displayed.

Any thoughts.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried already?
Otherwise it would just be spoon feeding

Comment: Please clearly state your question, your problem and post relevant code.

Comment: Are you displaying them in iframes or is it normal navigation?

Comment: I have already implemented some logic to get the required output. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UGHXv/). But with this implementation I am seeing this [Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372934/adding-sash-for-frames). Hence thinking to change the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a guideline:

You can address the [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent) of the [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) and trigger functions in it. Obviously those functions can address any child `iframe`.

For instance:

**Right frame Javascript:**

```
window.parent.changeLeftIframe();
```

**Parent Javascript:**

```
function changeLeftIframe() {
     document.getElementById("LeftFrame").change();
}
```

**Left frame Javascript:**

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById("LeftFrame").style = "background-color: red";
}
```

And there you go, you can manipulate one `iframe` from another one.

Answer (score 0):

At first, give `name`s to the `frame` elements. After that you can refer any frame's `window` object from any other frame or `frameset` window like this:

```
the_window_object_in_a_frame = top.frame_name;
```